# Move empty copy of db from windows to linux

Tags: linux, windows, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL db on a windows 7 machine. I need to create a copy of it on a Linux Mint machine.

Is there a way to create a template (or something?) from my existing db on the windows machine, then use it to create the same db on the Linux machine (with no data).

When I do this, will the primary keys for each table restart at 1 in the new db or do I have to manually do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sh
pg_dump --schema-only --host=DATABASE_IP --username=USERNAME DATBASE_NAME > schema.sql
```

Then run `schema.sql` on the Linux Mint machine.